# Django, use redis-py to lock in django views

Tags: django, django-views, redis

I'm trying to use redis to lock some of the big management Postgresql transaction I have in my project.
I haven't been successful so far on my development environment.

A simple version of the code would look like that:

```
def test_view(request):
  connec = redis.Redis(unix_socket_path='/tmp/vgbet_redis.sock')
  if not connec.setnx('test', ''):
    print 'Locked'
  else:
    time.sleep(5) #Slow transaction
    connec.delete('test')
    print 'Unlocked'
  return render_to_response("test.html")
```

If I open two tabs of that view, the first one print Unlocked after 5 seconds, then the second one prints Unlocked after 10 seconds. It looks like they are synchronous which doesn't make any sense to me.

**Edit:**
I have tried to install an apache and a gevent and I got the exact same results.

So I guess there is really something I don't understand with django + redis and my code is really wrong.

Any help would be great.

**Edit2:**
I just tried with django-redis by using redis as a cache.

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': '/tmp/vgbet_redis.sock',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'DB': 1,
      'PASSWORD': None,
      'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection.HiredisParser'
    },
  },
}
```

And I still have the same result if I open two tabs in my browser. The second view is blocked for 5 seconds, as if everything is synchronous.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
def test_view(request):
  if cache.get('test') != None:
    print 'Locked'
  else:
    cache.set('test', '', 60)
    time.sleep(5) #Slow transaction
    cache.delete('test')
  return render_to_response("test.html")
```

If I open two terminals, I have no issue reading and writing in redis. So I really don't understand why I'm not able to use the cache in views.

Comment: It should be noted: the locks you have there will not be atomic. It'd be better to use [setnx](http://redis.io/commands/setnx), which would prevent race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for my issue, was because I was using two tabs on my browser. If I use two browsers or two different IP, my code works asynchronously (with gevent and apache, not with runserver but this isn't a surprise).

I think there is something like: if a unique session asks for the same view multiple times, they are served synchronously. I don't know if it's due to the server or django. I can't find anything like that on the documentation. If anyone knows, I would be really interested to understand that last part.

Comment: Ah, this could be because your web browser will only open a certain number of connections to a particular server at any time. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Ah, weird. That should allow at least two connections.

Comment: if you were using `./manage.py runserver` I think the problem was that the Django dev server used to be single-threaded, so parallel connections from browser tabs could only run in series. It's now multithreaded since 1.4

Answer (score 2):

A couple things to check:

- The default Django development server is single-threaded, so can only handle one request at a time. The simplest way to test this would be to run the development server twice on different ports (ex, `./manage.py runserver 8080` and `./manage.py runserver 8081`).
- If you are using an SQL database at all, it *might* be blocking on a transaction. Are these the *exact* views you are using? Or are you doing anything with models?
- You mentioned using `gevent` — were you sure to call `from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()` to monkey patch everything? Also, how are you running your server with gevent?

Comment: I finally found my error, I just posted the answer.

Thank you very much for your answer, I love the advice of using two runserver, and I will definitively follow your recommendation of updating gevent.

Comment: Would you recommend to call the redis.Redis(...) in every view or to create a global ? Does it change anything ?

Comment: You should be creating a global. `Redis` (assuming that you're using `redis-py`) keeps an internal thread pool, so there's no reason not to make it global, and making it global will potentially speed things up (as a new TCP connection won't need to be established each time).